# How do i go to the next line without it adding in a <br/> tag using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, html

Every time I press enter to move on to my next line of code, it auto adds a break tag onto the end of my line.
I have tried (ENTER & SHIFT ENTER) and also have browsed all the settings.
How can I get rid of this feature. Not sure if that's suppose to happen or if theres a setting I can tweak.

Comment: What Language is your document set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in HTML/XML mode, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert `<br/>` tag automatically.

From the main menu TextFX > TextFX Settings, **disable** the 'Autoconvert typed HTML/XML to &entities'.

The screenshot below shows the switch in the enabled state.

[image]

Your problem should be solved.